# Call function with parameters from array - apply() without the context parameter?

Tags: javascript

Is there any method that invokes a function but sets the context `this` to the "default" value that it has when I invoke the function by doing `fn()`?

This method should accept an array and pass the single elements as arguments to the function, much like apply() does:

```
emitter = new EventEmitter();
args = ['foo', 'bar'];

// This is the desired result:
emitter.emit('event', args[0], args[1], ...);

// I can do this using apply, but need to set the context right
emitter.emit.apply(emitter, 'event', args);

// How can I trim the context from this?
emitter.emit.???('event', args);
```

*EDIT:* To clarify this, I do care about the value that `this` will have inside the called function - it needs to be the "normal" context it has when doing `emitter.emit()`, not the global object or anything else. Otherwise, this will break things sometimes.

Comment: What is the `"normal"` context then?

Comment: The value of `this` when I do `emitter.emit()` - `emitter` in that case, the object that the function is attached to in every other case.

Comment: `someObject.emit.apply(someObject, args)` then?

Comment: @Esailija yeah, that's what he's after - he just needs some syntactic sugar to avoid the repetition (per my updated answer)

Comment: @Esailija ah, no, there's more to it than that - he wants the first arg to be separate from the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the first parameter to the global object (i.e. `window` in a browser)

In ES3 browsers you could pass `null` instead and it would be automatically be changed to the global object, but that behaviour [has been removed in the ES5 specifications](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.3).

---

**EDIT** it sounds like you just need a new function:

```
EventEmitter.prototype.emitArgs = function(event, args) {
    this.emit.apply(this, [event].concat(args));
}
```

at which point you can just call:

```
emitter.emitArgs('event', args);
```

(**EDIT** thanks to @Esalija for `[].concat`)

Comment: It has not been removed but it only applies under strict mode http://es5.github.com/#C

Comment: Thanks, but this still does only a shallow copy of the array ;)

Comment: @Niko why would you need a deep copy?  If the `emit` function needs a deep copy it'll take one - this code is just an intermediary.

Comment: Hm, you're right - actually, I don't want one because emit() shouldn't get copies. Didn't get that right away.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass `null` or `undefined` if you don't care about the context. Inside the function, `this` [will then refer to the global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) when in non-strict mode [and to `null` respectively `undefined` in strict-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode#.22Securing.22_JavaScript).

A "default" context for a function is hard to define

```
function f() { return this };
a = { b: f }
c = a.b;

console.log(f());   # window
console.log(a.b()); # a
console.log(c());   # window
```

Which one of these is the "right" context?

In your case you might consider a utility function

```
/* you might call it something else */
emitter.emit_all = function (event, args) {
    return this.emit.apply(this, [event].concat(args));
}
```

Comment: neat - I didn't know that passing `null` automatically changed the context to the global object.

Comment: Thanks, but I need `this` to refer to the "normal" context, not the global object.

Comment: The "normal" context _is_ the global object.

Comment: ah, it seems this is the _old_ behaviour, and not supported in ES5.

Comment: Ok, bad wording there. If the function is attached to an object, the context is that object instead of the global object.

Comment: A function can be attached to multiple objects. If you want to attach the function to a specific object, you have to set it explicitly.

Comment: Ok, that does make sense. I was pretty much looking for a method that is able to "guess" this, but I see your point.

Comment: @Niko I edited my answer, the wrapper function should to the job

Comment: Thanks! This "spread" syntax is exactly what I am looking for (the answer unfortunately disappeared), but another function seems to be the best option right now.

Comment: @Niko: the spread operator is not available in current js: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:spread

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by the native Function "arguments" variable.

```
var EventEmitter = window.EventEmitter = function(){
    //this.emit = this.emit.bind(this);//bind emit to "this"
    return this;
};
EventEmitter.prototype.isMe = function(obj){
    return obj === this;
};
EventEmitter.prototype.emit = function(eventName){
    var input = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    console.log("this:%O, Emitting event:%s, with arguments:%O", this, eventName,input);
};

emitter = new EventEmitter();
emitter.emit('magicEvent', 'Zelda Con', 'Zork Meetup', 'etc');
```

To maintain the "this" context you could bind the emit method in the constructor, though this would create per instance "own" object properties increasing memory consumption and practically perform all prototype chain lookups (for bound methods) on object creation regardless if you needed them or not.