# .apply without changing scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I want to use the JavaScript .apply method to functions of a thrift compiled for Node.js. The thrift .js file has code like this:

```
...
var NimbusClient = exports.Client = function(output, pClass) {
    this.output = output;
    this.pClass = pClass;
    this.seqid = 0;
    this._reqs = {};
};
NimbusClient.prototype = {};
NimbusClient.prototype.getClusterInfo = function(callback) {
    this.seqid += 1; // line where error is thrown [0]
    this._reqs[this.seqid] = callback;
    this.send_getClusterInfo();
};
...
```

My server file looks the following way:

```
var thrift = require('thrift')
    , nimbus = require('./Nimbus')
    , connection = thrift.createConnection('127.0.0.1', 6627)
    , client = thrift.createClient(nimbus, connection)
    , ... // server initiation etc

app.get('/nimbus/:command', function(req, res, next) {
    client[req.params.command](console.log); // direct call [1]
    client[req.params.command].apply(this, [console.log]); // apply call [2]
});

...
```

The direct call [1] returns the values as expected, but the apply call [2] always produces the following error in line [0]:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'NaN' of undefined
```

I tried several other scope parameters in [2]: `null`, `nimbus`, `nimbus.Client`, `nimbus.Client.prototype`, `nimbus.Client.prototype[req.params.command]` and `client[req.params.command]`, all without success.

How can I call the apply method without changing the actual scope of the function called, so that it behaves exactly the same as it would if called in the direct way?

Comment: foo.apply(null,…) produces the same error

Comment: I'm kind of curious as to why you want to use the `apply` method in the first place if you wish to retain the default scope...

Comment: @subhaze: I boiled it down for this example. I need the number of arguments to be variable, because most Nimbus functions expect more than just the callback as parameters.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Have you tried `client[req.params.command].apply(client, [console.log]);` by chance?

Comment: Thanks a lot subhaze, that solved the problem for me! Strange, I thought I already tried that too. But the main question remains: Is there a way to use .apply() without changing the scope of the function?

Comment: this may be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536177/call-function-with-parameters-from-array-apply-without-the-context-parameter

Comment: Doing what I suggested should in fact be retaining the scope

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pointing the `apply` function back to the same function like this should retain the original scope.

```
client[req.params.command].apply(client, [console.log]);
```

Comment: This is exactly how [coffeescript compiles array splats as function arguments](http://tinyurl.com/baz8ryz) `obj.fn(arr...)`