# How to pass an arguments array to a function without changing context?

Tags: javascript

I am dealing with functions which are each bound to a specific context. Somewhere else in the code, I have to call them with a variable number of arguments. Normally, I would do it with `apply`, but that would change the context (`this`).

Can I achieve the effect of `apply( null, args )` without changing the existing, bound value of `this` in the function?

(I don't have the value of the functions's `this` at hand in a variable when the call needs to happen.)

Incidentally, the question here is not a duplicate of [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536177/call-function-with-parameters-from-array-apply-without-the-context-parameter) where, despite the promising title, the OP is just trying to add syntactic sugar to a method call.

Comment: Can you provide some example code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536177/call-function-with-parameters-from-array-apply-without-the-context-parameter

Comment: An example would be great. I can't think of something where you call `some.method.apply(null, args)` where you can't do `some.method.apply(some, args)` without the root of the problem being in the architecture of the code.

Comment: without calling function the `this` have to window ref in function, i am not sure if you have different ref in this inside function, even you can pass by `apply(window, args)` method

Comment: Use `apply( this, args )`. You say you don't have `this` in a variable, but surely you must have `this` in `this`, yes?

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina Yes, he seems to be asking the same question, thank you. (Didn't find it when I searched.) Or rather, the title fits; the actual content of the question is a bit confused, though, because there's more than just the context issue to fix. That confusion is reflected in the answers as well, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, it turns out this is a non-issue. If a function is bound to a context, it can safely be called with `apply` without the context changing.

The first argument of `apply` can be set to anything - `undefined`, `null`, `window`, another object. It doesn't have any effect if the function is bound.

Example:

```
var o = { id: "foo" },
    args = [ "bar", "baz" ],
    f = function () {
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments ).join( ", ");
      return "Called in the context of " + this.id + " with args " + args; 
    },

    // Binding f to o with ES5 bind
    boundNative = f.bind( o ),

    // Binding f to o with a closure
    boundWithClosure = ( function ( context ) { 
        return function () { 
            return f.apply( context, arguments ); 
        } 
    } )( o );

// Does boundNative.apply( whatever, args ) change the context?
console.log( boundNative.apply( undefined, args ) );
console.log( boundNative.apply( null, args ) );
console.log( boundNative.apply( window, args ) );
console.log( boundNative.apply( { id: "quux" }, args ) );

// Same test with the closure
console.log( boundWithClosure.apply( undefined, args ) );
console.log( boundWithClosure.apply( null, args ) );
console.log( boundWithClosure.apply( window, args ) );
console.log( boundWithClosure.apply( { id: "quux" }, args ) );
```

All calls return "Called in the context of foo with args bar, baz", so no issue.

I have to admit the result surprised me at first. After all, `apply` enforces a context - how come that is ignored? But in fact it makes perfect sense.

Yes, the *original* function (`f`) refers to `this`, and calling it with `apply` would change its value. But we are not calling the original function.

The bound function is an entirely separate entity, and it does not reference `this` any longer. It is not quite so obvious with ES5 `bind`, but the closure construct gives it away. The `this` keyword doesn't appear anywhere in the function which is returned by the IIFE. Calling that, there is nothing which `apply` can change.

Answer (score 0):

Context exists always, it can be global object (window) or context of some particular object. When you call a function, it uses some context. Also you should definitely have access to it. The function exist in visible scope (context and scope are not the same)

```
var text = "Current context is ";

function A() {
    this.test = "A";
    this.print = function(msg) {
        return msg + this.test;
    }
};

function B() {
    this.test = "B";
}

var testObj = {
    test: "testObj"
};

test = "window";

var msgFn = function (msg) {
    return msg + "msgFn";
}

var a = new A();
var b = new B();

a.print.apply(a, [text]); // Current context is A
a.print.apply(b, [text]); // Current context is B
a.print.apply(null, [text]); // Current context is window
a.print.apply(testObj, [text]); // Current context is testObj
msgFn.apply(msgFn, [text]); // // Current context is msgFn
```